# Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run

Tags: java, android

I get the following error message when building my android project in Developer Studio:

Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
1>     Your current JDK is located in  C:\Program Files\Android\jdk\jdk-8.0.302.8-hotspot\jdk8u302-b08\jre

but when I run ./gradlew --version, I get this:

Kotlin:       1.5.31
Groovy:       3.0.9
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          20 (Oracle Corporation 20+36-2344)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64

I do not know why it is pointing to C:\Program Files\Android\jdk\jdk-8.0.302.8-hotspot\jdk8u302-b08\jre

and I do not know where to fix it.

is there any help out there?

Answer (score 0):

Android document [set the JDK version](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config#jdk) 
[image: set the JDK version]

Comment: I do not have android studio. as I wrote in my message, I am using Developer Studio.

Comment: `./gradlew assembledebug` should be work if you run it in terminal. gradlew use JAVA_HOME or the default java you set in Path. IDE has their own config,you need to check the document according to your IDE. I'm sorry but what is the Developer Studio?